# 500 error on admin/actions/elementIndex/getElements

Tags: plugin-development, elementtype

Trying to get an element setup but when index is loaded, I get a "Unknown Error has occurred", diving into logs I found a 500 error was being thrown from the `admin/actions/elementIndex/getElements` url.

Full Element type code shown below.

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

/**
 * GoWander - Trip element type
 */
class GoWander_TripElementType extends BaseElementType
{
    /**
     * Returns the element type name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return Craft::t('Trips');
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether this element type has content.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasContent()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether this element type has titles.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasTitles()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns this element type's sources.
     *
     * @param string|null $context
     * @return array|false
     */
    public function getSources($context = null)
    {
        $sources = array(
            '*' => array(
                'label'    => Craft::t('All Trips'),
            )
        );

        foreach (craft()->goWander_template->findAll() as $template)
        {
            $key = 'template:'.$template->id;

            $sources[$key] = array(
                'label'    => $template->name,
                'criteria' => array('templateId' => $template->id)
            );
        }

        return $sources;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the attributes that can be shown/sorted by in table views.
     *
     * @param string|null $source
     * @return array
     */
    public function defineTableAttributes($source = null)
    {
        return array(
            'title'     => Craft::t('Title'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Returns the table view HTML for a given attribute.
     *
     * @param BaseElementModel $element
     * @param string $attribute
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTableAttributeHtml(BaseElementModel $element, $attribute)
    {
        return parent::getTableAttributeHtml($element, $attribute);
    }

    /**
     * Defines any custom element criteria attributes for this element type.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function defineCriteriaAttributes()
    {
        return array(
            'price'   => AttributeType::Mixed,
        );
    }

    /**
     * Modifies an element query targeting elements of this type.
     *
     * @param DbCommand $query
     * @param ElementCriteriaModel $criteria
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function modifyElementsQuery(DbCommand $query, ElementCriteriaModel $criteria)
    {
        $query
            ->addSelect('gowander_trips.templateId')
            ->join('gowander_trips trips', 'trips.id = elements.id');

        if ($criteria->price) {

            $query->andWhere(DbHelper::parseParam('gowander_trips.price', $criteria->price, $query->params));
        } 

    }

    /**
     * Populates an element model based on a query result.
     *
     * @param array $row
     * @return array
     */
    public function populateElementModel($row)
    {
        return GoWander_TripModel::populateModel($row);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the HTML for an editor HUD for the given element.
     *
     * @param BaseElementModel $element
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEditorHtml(BaseElementModel $element)
    {
        // Start/End Dates
        $html = craft()->templates->render('events/_edit', array(
            'element' => $element,
        ));

        // Everything else
        $html .= parent::getEditorHtml($element);

        return $html;
    }
}
```

error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'gowander_trips.templateId' in 'field list'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `elements`.`id`, `elements`.`type`, `elements`.`enabled`, `elements`.`archived`, `elements`.`dateCreated`, `elements`.`dateUpdated`, `elements_i18n`.`slug`, `elements_i18n`.`uri`, `elements_i18n`.`enabled` AS `localeEnabled`, `content`.`id` AS `contentId`, `content`.`title`, `content`.`field_body`, `gowander_trips`.`templateId`
```

Comment: The underlying error message for the 500 Internal Server Error will be logged in your `craft\storage\runtime\logs` folder.  Can you check there and share what the error is?

Comment: Updated with db error.

Comment: It's probably choking on `->addSelect('gowander_trips.templateId')`. I'd check wherever you set that relationship up.

Comment: Relationship follows same format as events example plugin, and it exists in table. Really stuck on what this could be. Code works if I change db queries over to events example so it must be something db related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally discovered the solution to this, it was as Brad had suggested due to the query - however it was my incidental prepending of the plugin name to the table. ie. "gowander_trips" vs. "trips". After some digging and looking at other plugins it seems Craft does add the plugin name for you.